Blazor Webassembly / C# .NET - Poor Performance / Comparison with C# .NET
Problem
My team of developers is transitioning from C#/WPF to Blazor/Web-Assembly. We are building very big and complex ui-application. During our first prototyp we encounted a very large and for us even crazy and unexplainable performance issue with blazor C#/.NET. It seems like complex C#/NET Code in Loops is running very slow. We found similar issues in several different technical use-cases.
Test-Case
To be able to post this here, we excracted this isse in to the following very simple test-case:
List<MyClass> classList = new List<MyClass>();
int counter = 10000;
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    var c = new MyClass();

    c.Prop1 = "test";
    c.Prop2 = 1;

    classList.Add(c);
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string? Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int? Prop2 { get; set; }
}

Performance
We then compared the code-snippet above, running on Blazor/Webassembly in Chrome vs. running on C#/WPF.
Which leads uns to the following meassured Performance (times in ms, same hardware, .NET 8, meassured times are avg. of 10 tries, wpf fully built is even faster and there for not recorded):



counter
Blazor/Debug
Blazor/Publish
WPF/Debug




10.000
1.300  ms
180    ms
10  ms


100.000
12.000 ms
1.400  ms
250 ms



Conclusion
We expected an somewhat closer to native performance.
On the other hand is, everything UI and Blazor/Razor-Component related seems to be very fast.
Debugging Performance
We were most suprised about the crazy difference in performance in the "Debugger" using the same Visual-Studio 2022. We know that debuggin creates an overhead, but on Blazor-Debugger the code takes about 50!! times longer to run than on C#/WPF-Debugger.
Life/Published  Performance
Then we compared the performance for published Blazor/Webassembly vs C#/WPF.
And still the code takes about 5!! times longer to run on Blazor than on C#/WPF in Debugger.
Unanswered Questions
Is there anything we can to a) speed up performance during debugging and b) to get somewhat better (closer to nativ) performance for C#-Code-Execution?
Has anyone meassured/expierenced something similar and maybe even found some improvements for this?

The code you've posted certainly isn't your actual code- int counter = 10.000; wouldn't compile. That makes me wonder what else is different about your code.

thanks i edited this, in our code we had this an getter/setter so we can change it from outside, to make it more simple / easier to read i copied the actual value here.

There is no point to compare WPF and WASM because the first one uses .NET runtime and second a custom WASM runtime in the browser. .NET runtime will provide you with a UI thread and a worker thread. Chrome WASM VM (does?) might not. Also WASM VM will definitely generate differently opimized low-level code. I would say you have to profile your code first and then come back with a question "how to optimize XYZ".

The code is full of reallocations and garbage collections of the list's internal buffer, creating log2(counter) temporary objects and taking almost twice the RAM. That's slow in a desktop app and a lot slower in something that runs in a single browser tab, using a single thread for everything. Specify an initial capacity for the list and then check the difference.

It is not clear from your post, but is your publish using AOT? It is absolutely necessary to use AOT for performance. It compiles assemblies instead of being interpreted and that makes a world of difference. Being in release, but not AOT does make it better compared to slow debug as there is incredible overhead to debug it.
